# Validating Dynamically Generated EditTexts

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have a class where the user is able to dynamically generate EditText views. I'm aiming to validate them to check whether they are empty when the user continues to the next page. If they are, then the validation triggers and it halts the process of moving to the other page until the user fills the EditText fields he/she created.

Here is what I have:

**EditText generation**

```
int EditTextID = 5000;
insertPoint = findViewById(R.id.questionsContainer);

if(v.getId() == R.id.makeLayoutButton){

    //get form template which has an EditText of id "questionAnswerEt"
    v1 = vi.inflate(R.layout.form_template, null);

    //add it into my view
    ((LinearLayout) insertPoint).addView(v1);

    v1.setId(formParentID);

    //get edittext
    questionAnswer = (EditText)v1.findViewById(R.id.questionAnswerET);

    //set id
    questionAnswer.setId(EditTextID);

    EditTextID++;
}
```

**Validation**

```
if(v.getId() == R.id.bNext){
    for(int x = 5000; x <= 5007; x++){
        questionAnswer = (EditText)findViewById(x);
        String questionAnswerValidator = (String) questionAnswer.getText().toString();

        if(questionAnswerValidator.length() == 0){
           ((EditText) questionAnswer.findViewById(x))
           .setError( "Question Title is Required!" );
        }
    }
}
```

The loop starts at 5000 because the generated EditTexts have manually set IDs that start from 5000 and then increment each time the user decides to generate another EditText. I'm then getting the EditText by looping through the IDs by referencing "questionAnswer". I'm then putting the string value of questionAnswer(id of x) into a String "questionAnswerValidator". Which is then checked to see if its empty and if it is it'll produce a setError message on the appropriate EditTexts which are empty. Problem is that the app is crashing when the validation starts giving me a null pointer exception. Any clue as to where I'm going wrong? Thank you.

**Log:**

```
08-27 14:27:02.084: W/dalvikvm(16285): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4166fe18)
08-27 14:27:02.084: E/AndroidRuntime(16285): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-27 14:27:02.084: E/AndroidRuntime(16285): Process: com.example.testing, PID: 16285
08-27 14:27:02.084: E/AndroidRuntime(16285): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-27 14:27:02.084: E/AndroidRuntime(16285):    at com.example.testing.MakeQuestion.onClick(MakeQuestion.java:212)
08-27 14:27:02.084: E/AndroidRuntime(16285):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4480)
08-27 14:27:02.084: E/AndroidRuntime(16285):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18686)
08-27 14:27:02.084: E/AndroidRuntime(16285):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-27 14:27:02.084: E/AndroidRuntime(16285):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-27 14:27:02.084: E/AndroidRuntime(16285):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
08-27 14:27:02.084: E/AndroidRuntime(16285):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
08-27 14:27:02.084: E/AndroidRuntime(16285):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-27 14:27:02.084: E/AndroidRuntime(16285):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-27 14:27:02.084: E/AndroidRuntime(16285):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
08-27 14:27:02.084: E/AndroidRuntime(16285):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
08-27 14:27:02.084: E/AndroidRuntime(16285):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: also put code of button click i think you are not registering button onClickListener(this);

Comment: @andruboy It is registering the button click. I have validation on static EditText fields and its working fine when the user clicks on "bNext". Its when I added the validation for the dynamic EditTexts that it started crashing.

Comment: What's line MakeQuestion.java:212?

Answer (score 0):

try this code for validating `TextUtil.isEmpty(questionAnswerValidator)` is check for null and 0 length

```
String questionAnswerValidator;
if(v.getId() == R.id.bNext){
for(int x = 5000; x <= 5007; x++){
    questionAnswer = (EditText)findViewById(x);
    questionAnswerValidator = questionAnswer.getText().toString();

    if(TextUtil.isEmpty(questionAnswerValidator)){
       questionAnswer.setError( "Question Title is Required!" );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I was going out of bounds in the loop. This did the trick:

```
for(int x = 5000; x < EditTextID; x++){
    questionAnswer = (EditText)findViewById(x);
    if(questionAnswer.getText().toString().length() == 0){  
        questionAnswer.setError( "Question Title is Required!" );
    }
}
```

Only problem is that its now showing the setError icon on the appropriate empty EditTexts fields but withholding the error message until I start typing in the respective EditText. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

As Frisbetarian told you, you can use his answer and add .requestFocus for the error to appear in the EditText. Note that the EditText that shows the last error will receive the focus of the error, until you fill that EditText in particular.

```
for(int x = 5000; x < EditTextID; x++){
    questionAnswer = (EditText)findViewById(x);
    if(questionAnswer.getText().toString().length() == 0){  
        questionAnswer.setError( "Question Title is Required!" );
        questionAnswer.requestFocus();

    }
}
```